# Why am i getting this error (arising from a use of ‘print’)

Tags: haskell, ghci

I did something like this:

```
data Peca = Peca Tipo Altura
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show) 

type Altura = Int 

data Tipo = Rampa Orientacao | Curva Orientacao | Recta | Lava
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

isLavva:: [Peca] -> Tipo -> [Peca]
islavva [] _ = []
isLavva ((Peca h a):t) x |h==x = (Peca h a):isLavva t x
                         |otherwise = isLavva t x
```

Don't mind the names in portuguese... When i try isLavva [Peca Lava 0] it just says

```
isLavva [Peca Lava 0,Peca Lava 0,Peca Recta 0]

<interactive>:45:1:
No instance for (Show (Tipo -> [Peca]))
  (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
  arising from a use of ‘print’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: it's just missing this
    data Orientacao = Norte | Este | Sul | Oeste
      deriving (Eq,Read,Show,Enum)

Comment: `isLavva` takes two arguments and you're only supplying one, resulting in a function of one argument that the REPL cannot display. Supply a value of type `Tipo` to `isLavva`.

Comment: i put 'isLavva ((Peca h a):t) x' and i supposed the x would be the 'Tipo' ... I'm not sure though, but thanks :)

Comment: Your problem is when calling `isLavva` i.e. in `isLavva [Peca Lava 0,Peca Lava 0,Peca Recta 0]`. There you are only supplying the first argument but you need to supply two e.g. `isLavva [Peca Lava 0,Peca Lava 0,Peca Recta 0] Recta`.

Comment: oh yeah thank you so much... ' [Peca Lava 0,Peca Lava 0*** Exception: Tarefa2_2017li1g80.hs:(163,1)-(164,49): Non-exhaustive patterns in function isLavva
 ' now it's this error though :D i can't get nothing right

Comment: oh wait i resolved it xD it was the lower case l in islavva [ ] _